How can unknown properties be configured as a hard error in Bicep?
I am linting some Bicep files programmatically. I would like to make sure az bicep lint treats unknown resource properties or missing resource type information as hard errors.
For example, the following Bicep script should not pass linting:
resource invalidResource 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid('whatever')
  scope: resourceGroup()
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: ''
    principalId: ''
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    // This property should result in a hard error
    unknownProperty: ''
  }
}

However, it currently just results in a warning:
$ az bicep lint --file demo.bicep 

demo.bicep(8,5) : Warning BCP037: The property "unknownProperty" is not allowed on objects of type "RoleAssignmentProperties". Permissible properties include "condition", "conditionVersion", "delegatedManagedIdentityResourceId", "description". If this is an inaccuracy in the documentation, please report it to the Bicep Team. [https://aka.ms/bicep-type-issues]

I know I can provide a bicep configuration file to promote warnings to errors, but as of today none of the linting options seem to cover this.


Fetching unknown properties be configured as a hard error in Bicep

As per the Bicep linter  Documentation it doesn't have enough privilege to show all warnings as errors because of limitation.
Instead we can use customized PowerShell script to the task for you. This way can be help full to fetch the warning as error.
For demo I took the sample bicep file as the one which you took which was included with unknownproperties.
demo.bicep:
resource invalidResource 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid('whatever')
  scope: resourceGroup()
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: ''
    principalId: ''
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    // This property should result in a hard error
    unknownProperty: ''
  }
}

now the custom PowerShell script int_bicep.ps1 this will fetch the keywords like warnings from the bicep linter output and show these warnings as errors at the output.
int_bicep.ps1
$linterOutput = az bicep lint --file demo.bicep 2>&1

# Split the output into lines
$linterOutputLines = $linterOutput -split "`r?`n"

# Check for warnings that should be treated as errors
$hasError = $false
foreach ($line in $linterOutputLines) {
    if ($line -match 'Warning') {
        $hasError = $true
        break
    }
}

# Exit with error code if any critical issues found
if ($hasError) {
    Write-Error "Error: Found forbidden property 'unknownProperty' in Bicep file."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Output "No critical issues found in Bicep file."
    exit 0
}

Output:

Refer:
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

Thanks Vinay. Unfortunately we're calling the bicep linter via Megalinter, so we can't add custom scripting to transform warnings. Looks like this issue confirms there's no support for this currently: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/5286

Yes, @sardobi It was just an alternative walkaround as it doesn't have any direct approach supporting for the requirement.

Unfortunately this approach does not solve my problem
